# Merging data frames if date is in time frame

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am new to python and I am stuck to a problem for which I did not find a solution up to now:
I would like to merge two data frames:
df1: containing the coverage date of a contract
df2: containing event data to these contracts

Now I am looking for ways to to conditionally merge df2 on df1 (by left join), but only in case the following condition is fulfilled:
CovStartDate <= EventDate <= CovEndDate

An alternative workaround would be just to do the left merge and apply the condition afterwards and to delete duplicates, but I thought there must be a smarter solution to this.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: In similar cases I usually use `merge_asof` and depending on the requirements merge either data greater or less than the corresponding data in the second dataframe and then use a condition to remove duplicates just as you planned. I think this is the only real way of doing it.

Comment: To get the best help, add dummy dataset